# Odd behavior with Python regular expressions - findall only finds the "()?" portion

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently writing a regular expression to find the units and size (or it could work as dimensions) in a string.  For example: "Product: A, 2 x 3.5 gallon bottles"

For simplicity, I'm removing all whitespace, so this becomes:

"Product:A,2x3.5gallonbottles"

My regex is as follows:

```
numAndSize = re.compile(r'\d+[xX]\d+(\.\d+)?')
```

But when I try to use findall, this happens:

```
In [47]: numAndSize.findall("Product:A,2x3.5gallonbottles")
Out[47]: ['.5']
```

I -only- get the '.5' in this string, instead of the entire expression

Using search and group, however, works as expected:

```
In [50]: numAndSize.search("Product:A,2x3.5gallonbottles").group(0)
Out[50]: '2x3.5'
```

From there, I tried changing my regex to not include the optional decimal, and ran findall on that.

```
In [51]: numAndSize = re.compile(r'\d+[xX]\d+')
In [52]: numAndSize.findall("Product:A,2x3.5gallonbottles")
Out[52]: ['2x3']
```

Is there a reason behind this behavior?  For my purposes I can certainly use .search().group(), but I personally like findall since the output gives back a lot more information in a clean format.

Comment: Nothing odd about it; this is documented behaviour. Use a non-capturing group instead.

Comment: Martijin: It does look to be a duplicate now that I see it.  I didn't know what to look for when I made this question, so that passed by me.

Comment: That's fine; that's why duplicate questions are usually not deleted; they act as signposts on the way to the correct question and answer.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't expect it to be too much of a problem.  And as to why I thought it was odd, most of my regular expressions in the past have been written in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the regular expression contains any capturing groups, `re.findall()` will return those groups instead of the entire match.  To get the entire match use a non-capturing group:

```
>>> numAndSize = re.compile(r'\d+[xX]\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
>>> numAndSize.findall("Product:A,2x3.5gallonbottles")
['2x3.5']
```

Or if you could take advantage of this behavior to have it return a tuple of the dimensions (or units or whatever they are):

```
>>> numAndSize = re.compile(r'(\d+)[xX](\d+(?:\.\d+)?)')
>>> numAndSize.findall("Product:A,2x3.5gallonbottles")
[('2', '3.5')]
```

Comment: Aha, I tried and this definitely works.  I'll accept this answer in a few minutes - apparently the site isn't letting me do so yet.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a capture-group by using `()`.  [The documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

If you don't actually want to capture the fractional portion, use a non-capturing group:

```
numAndSize = re.compile(r'\d+[xX]\d+(?:\.\d+)?')
```